# Selecting only polygons that contain another polygon with Select by Location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, select-by-location, select-by-expression

In QGIS 3.16.11 on Windows 10 I have a layer with single polygons.

Given this polygon layer with, I'm trying to select only the polygons that that contain at least one other polygon (A & B)

[image]

1. My first thought was, gonna be easy just do:

   Research tools -> Select by Location

   ```
   INPUT: original_layer  
   INTERSECT: original_layer  
   PREDICATE: contain
   ```

   But everything got selected. It's acting like *contain* select polygon that contain *but also that are equal*. same thing happens with *are within*.
2. Then I tried with intermediary layer of slightly inflated polygons and to do the *contain* on that layer

   Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer

   ```
   INPUT: original_layer  
   DISTANCE: 0.00001
   OUPUT: inner_polygon_slighly_inflated
   ```

   Research tools -> Select by Location

   ```
   INPUT: original_layer  
   INTERSECT: inner_polygon_slighly_inflated  
   PREDICATE: contain
   ```

   Then I got selected **B**, but not **A**.

Can't find a way to this and which seems quite simple. Is there a way to make a `PREDICATE`: *contain but not equal*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression: `overlay_contains(@layer)`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that! This "select by expression" opens a whole new realm of possibility, I've seen virtual layer using SQL syntax. So much things to learn!

Comment: Indeed! I have the impression that QGIS expressions are easier to understand than SQL syntax - especially as you have the Help at hand wherever you use expressions (expand `Show Help` on top left of the expression builder).

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension to [@Babel's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412013/99589) which I found absolutely efficient.

Hence the statement *"selecting only polygons that contain another polygon"* was not really clear to me, I think some users may find it also a bit obscure. So there must be a differentiation between **(1)** *selecting only polygons that contain another polygon as filled holes* and **(2)** *selecting only polygons that contain another polygon that lay over*.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'poly_test'*, see image below.

[image: input]

### Case 1. Selecting only polygons that contain another polygon as filled holes

#### selecting polygons like `"id" = 5` but not `"id" = 1`

[image: case_1]
P.S. Here I moved the feature with `"id" = 6` for visual purposes

In the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) from the Selection Toolbar use the following expression

```
overlay_touches(@layer) and num_interior_rings($geometry)
```

and get the final output

[image: result_1]

### Case 2. Selecting only polygons that contain another polygon that lay over, i.e.

#### selecting polygons like `"id" = 2` but not `"id" = 5`

[image: case_2]

In the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) from the Selection Toolbar use the following expression

```
overlay_contains(@layer) and num_interior_rings($geometry)
```

and get the final output

[image: result_2]

### Case 3. Selecting both from Case 1 & 2

In the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) from the Selection Toolbar use the following expression

```
(overlay_contains(@layer) or overlay_touches(@layer)) and num_interior_rings($geometry)
```

and get the final output

[image: result_3]