# Selecting within feature which are in one polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I have a polygon which has features within it (inside it). It want to select these within features so that I can delete it. These are all in a single polygon layer.

I have tried QGIS's "Select by location" and GRASS GIS's `v.select` but I could not get the features that I wanted since the select features from and by comparing are the same layer.

In the image below I want to select the select me portions = 2 features only

[image: example]

Comment: see this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412013/87346 and use overlay_within(@layer) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed.